# Why I am getting this "NameError: name 'trainingData' is not defined"

Tags: python-3.x, nameerror

I a trying to import training.txt data as follows.

```
def readTrainingData(training):
    
    trainingData=[]
    
    with open(training.txt) as f:
        
        for line in f:
            a1, a2 = line.strip().split()
            trainingData.append((a1, a2))
    return trainingData
```

After that I am trying to use the traingdata to mesure some score as follows:

```
for pair in trainingData:
  linkScores[pair[0]+''+pair[1]]= computeProximityScore(pair[0],pair[1],'Jaccard',neighbors)
```

But it's giving an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-2532640f4771> in <module>
----> 1 trainingData

NameError: name 'trainingData' is not defined
```

Would anybody help me,please?

Thanks

Comment: How you called the function when you test it?

Comment: I am using the below command as a next step: for pair in trainingData:
  linkScores[pair[0]+''+pair[1]]= computeProximityScore(pair[0],pair[1],'Jaccard',neighbors).

Comment: You need to call the function first or update your code. the variable ```trainingData``` is defined inside the function so in other places Python won't recognized that variable outside of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand what you have tried to when you passed the variable `training` to the function.
But when you open a file you need to do it like that:

````
```with open("file_name.txt") as f:```
````

Also, you can't access the variable `trainingData` outside of the function.

I updated your code(I hope its what you intended to):

**Main( Or any other place you run the function):**

```
trainingData = readTrainingData("training.txt")
# The rest of your code.
```

**Your Function:**

```
def readTrainingData(training):
    trainingData = []

    with open(training) as f:
        for line in f:
            a1, a2 = line.strip().split()
            trainingData.append((a1, a2))
    return trainingData
```